# Unable to resolve module `./index.android` from The module `./index.android` could not be found from Indeed, none of these files exist:

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

error generate when i connect facebook auth with react-native using firebase

```
fbAuth() {
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions([
  "public_profile",
  "user_friends",
  "email"
]).then(
  result => {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      Alert.alert("Whoops!", "You cancelled the sign in.");
    } else {
      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
        const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
          data.accessToken
        );
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithCredential(credential)
          .then(loginUserSuccess(dispatch))
          .catch(error => {
            loginSingUpFail(dispatch, error.message);
          });
      });
    }
  },
  error => {
    Alert.alert("Sign in error", error);
  }
);}
```

having and issue with no module found this is my code where i integrate fb auth code

Comment: Please post the full error message!

Comment: thanks for reply error resolved

Comment: @ImranAli How did you resolve? I'm having this strange error.

Comment: add a file name index.android and import in it app.js

Answer (score 0):

The way you import files is wrong. Check out the path you are importing and correct it. It will work